# How to send mail to gmail account using ssmtp

Tags: ssl, ssmtp, gmail

I have the following ssmtp.conf file:

```
root=test@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
hostname=ed424cef9b52
UseTLS=Yes
UseStartTTLS=Yes
AuthMethod=LOGIN
AuthUser=test
AuthPass=test
FromLineOverride=yes
TLS_CA_File=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I can connect to 587 gmail port:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 64.233.186.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
```

But when I try to send mail:

```
/usr/sbin/ssmtp -v test@gmail.com < qq
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587

echo test | mailx  -s "testing ssmtp setup" test@gmail.com
send-mail: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

Comment: `UseStartTTLS=Yes` is probably wrong, a `T` too many.

Comment: Yup, shame on me! Now it asking me the App password of Google :-/

Comment: At gmail it should be port 465.  `mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465`

Comment: Here are the proper instructions for what you are trying to do:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail/363815#363815

Answer (score 11):

**The proper port is 465**

[Simplest way to send mail with image attachment from command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381131/simplest-way-to-send-mail-with-image-attachment-from-command-line-using-gmail/381132#381132)

---

EXCERPT:

Install ssmtp with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then go into /etc/ssmtp and edit ssmtp.conf to look like this:

```
root=rpi3abc@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=rpi3abc@gmail.com
AuthPass=testing123
UseTLS=YES
```

Send a one-liner like so:

```
echo "Testing...1...2...3" | ssmtp myusername@gmail.com
```

---

Send a formatted text file like so:

```
cat mymessage | ssmtp myusername@gmail.com
```

Where mymessage can be formatted to have lines for TO: and SUBJECT:  and the body.

```
TO: abc@def.com
SUBJECT: Testing
     -blank line-
Message body goes here....
```

Comment: And I got:
ssmtp: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor s3sm1189087qkj.118 - gsmtp)

Is this because google turned on two-factor authentication?

Comment: Fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736062/sending-email-fails-when-two-factor-authentication-is-on-for-gmail