# Simplest way to send mail with image attachment from command line using gmail?

Tags: email, ssmtp, gmail

Building on the previous post where the requirement was to have cron jobs send status messages via a single command line, as posted here:

[Simplest way to send one-line mail out via command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail)

The question came up as to how to use a single line to send an attachment file.

Scenario:

cron job generates the output file like so:

```
cd /home/pi/python
gnuplot plt12
```

the program file plt12 includes the following two lines:

```
set output "pl12.png"
set terminal png font "arial,11"
```

This is being done on a Rpi3B system connected via USB to a Nano for the ADC which does the data logging.

So, the question is, what is the easiest way to send that plot file image, using a single command line, via gmail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on that previous question referenced in the OP, the easiest way to send a message with a single command line is done like so:

[Simplest way to send one-line mail out via command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail)

---

EXCERPT:

Install `ssmtp` with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then go into /etc/ssmtp and edit ssmtp.conf to look like this:

```
root=rpi3abc@gmail
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=rpi3abc@gmail.com
AuthPass=testing123
UseTLS=YES
```

Send a one-liner like so:

```
echo "Testing...1...2...3" | ssmtp myusername@gmail.com
```

---

Once that part is complete, then to send an attachment with one line is equally simple.

First, install `mpack`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpack
```

then, following the scenario of having the file pl12.png to send to user abc@def.com, it is accomplished with the following single command line:

```
mpack -s "12-Volt Battery Pack plot" /home/pi/python/pl12.png abd@def.com
```

If the file is in the current directory, then it is not necessary to use a fully-qualified path.

`cron` jobs always run in the user's home directory, so it is always good practice to use a full directory path to the attachment file.

---

Comment: root parameter in the config should be gmail.com not gmail

Answer (score 6):

With `mutt`:

```
SMTP_URL='smtps://user:password@smtp.gmail.com' mutt \
  -F /dev/null \
  -e 'set from="Me <user@gmail.com>"' \
  -e 'set smtp_url=$SMTP_URL' \
  -s 'pl12.png file' \
  -a pl12.png --  \
  someone@example.com << EOM
Hi,

see pl12.png attached.

-- 
Me
EOM
```

Like every shell code, you can always put it on one line if that takes your fancy, though that doesn't help with legibility:

```
printf 'Hi,\n\nsee pl12.png attached\n\n-- \nMe\n' | SMTP_URL='smtps://user:password@smtp.gmail.com' mutt -F /dev/null -e 'set from="Me <user@gmail.com>"' -e 'set smtp_url=$SMTP_URL' -s 'pl12.png file' -a pl12.png  -- someone@example.com
```

Comment: It must be `-a filenames --` have a look at the `mutt --help`